# Problems converting PDF to DjVu

Tags: pdf, djvu

I have a PDF file (copyrighted, so I can't include it here). I'm trying to convert it to DjVu, using some online websites as well as `pdf2djvu`, but they all fail. In the case of `pdf2djvu`, the error was:

> PDF error: FoFiType1::parse a line has more than 255 characters, we don't support this

Is there any way around this? How do I deal with PDF to DjVu conversion problems?

Comment: Removed comments since the OP has already seen them and they were specific to the one file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by limitations in the version of libpoppler that pdf2djvu is using, triggered by specific fonts, and because of the way `pdf2djvu` handles them.

Opening such a file in `evince` (from an X based terminal) will show you the same error messages with `FoFiType1` under Ubuntu 12.04. Since evince ignores the errors it can display the file.

What you can do on 12.04 is convert the file to postscript, then back to pdf, then run pdf2djvu:

```
pdf2ps all.pdf
ps2pdf all.ps all2.pdf
pdf2djvu all2.pdf -o all2.djvu
```